# Парсинг Twitter python

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Выполнил авторизацию:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

HEADERS = 'Тут user-agent'

url = 'https://twitter.com/sessions'

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(url, headers = {
    'User-Agent': HEADERS
})

post_requests = session.post(url, {
     'username': 'логин',
     'password': 'пароль' 
})
```

Далее нужно перейти на https://twitter.com/elonmusk/followers и спарсить первых 100 фолловеров, но когда перехожу:

```
s = session.get('https://twitter.com/home', headers = HEADERS)
soup = BS(s.content, "html.parser")
title = soup.find("span", class_ = 'css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0').text
print(title)
```

получаю ошибку:

```
for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Пожалуйста помогите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session.get` в параметре `headers` ожидает `dictionary` с HTTP заголовками, а не строку.

```
s = session.get('https://twitter.com/home', headers = {
    'User-Agent': HEADERS,
})
```

Точно так же, как вы уже делали при авторизации.

Comment: `soup = BS(s.content, "html.parser")
title = soup.find("span", class_ = 'css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0')
print(title)` сделал как вы написали, но при попытке парсинга выдает None